# Is there a link function $g$ which is a monotonic function with $g(0) = 0$?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, link-function

I am working on a machine learning project (similar to this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04136). For this I need to make an assumption that a link function is monotonic and takes value $0$ at $0$. Thus my question is :

Is there a link function $g$ which is a monotonic function with $g(0) = 0$?

Comment: The identity link function?

Comment: Yeah, that's the obvious one. But are there other examples?

Comment: What do you want it to do? There are $f(x)=x^3$, $e^x-1$,…basically any monotonic function minus that function evaluated at zero will satisfy your criteria, though the statistical utility is not clear.

Comment: tanh is monotonic increasing and fixes 0 and is popular in ML. Any other requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Dave said in comments, given any monotonically increasing function $f(x)$, the function $g(x)$ will fulfill the properties you mentioned if

$$g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$$